# phonegap: How to play a local sound audio?

Tags: cordova

I have put my sounds files (**tictac.mp3**) in the root (where the index.html)

I use this function:

```
function playAudio(src) {
    console.log("playAudio "+src);
    var media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
    media.play({numberOfLoops: 1}); 
}
function onSuccess() {
    console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
}

function onError(error) {
    console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

and call `playAudio("tictac.mp3");`

I don't have any sound on my android and my application and my application logs on my android just gives me:

```
playAudio tictac.mp3
```

**No sound at all !, no success neither error**

My config.xml has these lines:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"  />
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I also tried with this code

```
function playAudio(src) {
    console.log("PlayAudio");
    if (typeof Audio != "undefined") { 
        new Audio(src).play() ;

    // Phonegap media
    } else if (typeof device != "undefined") {
        console.log("Phonegap media");
        // Android needs the search path explicitly specified
        if (device.platform == 'Android') {

            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
            console.log("Android", src);
        }

        var mediaRes = new Media(src,
            function onSuccess() {
                // release the media resource once finished playing
                mediaRes.release();
            },
            function onError(e){
                console.log("error playing sound: " + JSON.stringify(e));
            });
        mediaRes.play();

    } else {
        console.log("no sound API to play: " + src);
    }
 }
```

**Should I include cordoba.js or phonegap.js to my project ?**

(I use the phonegap build service)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the full example from the Cordova Documentation?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Media Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        playAudio("http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3");
    }

    // Audio player
    //
    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    // Play audio
    //
    function playAudio(src) {
        if (my_media == null) {
            // Create Media object from src
            my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
        } // else play current audio
        // Play audio
        my_media.play();

        // Update my_media position every second
        if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    // Pause audio
    //
    function pauseAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    //
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    //
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause Playing Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="stopAudio();">Stop Playing Audio</a>
    <p id="audio_position"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No: beacuse it is TOO complex and long and beacuse it uses HTTP source file and NOT LOCAL

Comment: ...replace the link to the external file with your local url?!